# Infix To Postfix Conceptual

Tags: c++, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm currently studying for a final right now, and this is something I never understood how to do. On one of my homework questions, I was asked whether some provided postfix expressions were valid or invalid. Is there any surefire way to know this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. The only valid postfix operators are postfix-`++` and postfix-`--`.

Comment: Parse it and if there is an error then it is invalid.

Comment: For example, say on a test I'm asked:

Comment: So example `**myValue;` is wrong but `++myValue;` is correct.

Comment: Is this expression: 5 + 9 2 5 + *     valid or invalid?

Comment: How would I know how to answer that on the spot? Without a compiler. This is purely academic of course

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. So this expression isn't valid. `5 9 + 3 *` is valid. You have to 'keep/stack' the first 2 numbers, then catch the operator and apply it to your stack (where you have in this example 5 and 9). Then you will calculate 5 + 9 and stack the result in your stack. You will store the next number and try to find an operator. I hope it helps you a little to understand. You can check [RPN on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! By far the most concise explanation I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate it. Push each number; when you encounter an operator, pop two values, apply the operator to them, and push the result. There should be no stack underflows, and at the end there should be exactly one stack element.